CouchDB view returns error: undef on Ubuntu 22
We have recently migrated our Ubuntu from 20 to 22, now the problem when using Ubuntu 22 is the Couchb. I have CouchDB 3.3.3 installed on both 20 & 22, but only ubuntu 20 works fine. For ubuntu 22 similar view with javascript code didn't work.
view-sessions_by_user_ref-map (view file)
function(doc) {
    if (doc.type == 'sessionmanagersessiondoc') {
        emit(doc.user_ref, {
            'user_name': doc.user_name,
            'expiry_time': doc.expiry_time,
            'last_updated': doc.last_updated,
            'comment': doc.comment});
    }
}

This is the return.
{
    "error": "{undef,[{couch_ejson_compare,get_collator_version,[],[]},\n        {couch_mrview_util,update_collator_versions,1,\n                       [{file,\"src/couch_mrview_util.erl\"},{line,1333}]},\n        {couch_mrview_util,init_state,4,\n                           [{file,\"src/couch_mrview_util.erl\"},{line,344}]},\n        {couch_mrview_index,init_and_upgrade_state,4,\n                        [{file,\"src/couch_mrview_index.erl\"},{line,329}]},\n        {couch_mrview_index,open,2,\n                            [{file,\"src/couch_mrview_index.erl\"},{line,135}]},\n        {couch_index,'-init/1-fun-0-',3,\n                     [{file,\"src/couch_index.erl\"},{line,78}]},\n        {couch_util,with_db,2,[{file,\"src/couch_util.erl\"},{line,572}]},\n   {couch_index,init,1,[{file,\"src/couch_index.erl\"},{line,77}]}]}",
    "reason": "{gen_server,call,\n    [index_server_1,\n     {get_index,\n         {couch_mrview_index,\n             {mrst,\n      <<57,223,102,9,37,185,190,225,163,76,226,3,131,31,109,177>>,\n         nil,undefined,\n                 <<\"shards/80000000-ffffffff/sessionmanager.1715319230\">>,\n          <<\"_design/main\">>,<<\"javascript\">>,[],false,\n                 {[]},\n                 [{mrview,0,0,0,\n                      [<<\"sessions_by_user_ref\">>],\n                      [],\n           <<\"function(doc) {\\n    if (doc.type == 'sessionmanagerdsessiondoc') {\\n        emit(doc.user_ref, {\\n            'user_name': doc.user_name,\\n            'last_updated': doc.last_updated,\\n      'comment': doc.comment});\\n    }\\n}\">>,\n                      nil,[]},\n                  {mrview,1,0,0,\n                      [<<\"sessions_no_expiry\">>],\n                      [],\n             <<\"function(doc) {\\n    if (doc.type == 'sessionmanagersessiondoc' && doc.expiry_time == 0) {\\n        emit(doc.last_updated, doc.ref);\\n    }\\n}\\n\">>,\n                      nil,[]},\n        {mrview,2,0,0,\n                      [<<\"sessions_by_expiry_time\">>],\n                      [],\n        <<\"function(doc) {\\n    if (doc.type == 'sessionmanagersessiondoc' && doc.expiry_time > 0) {\\n        emit(doc.expiry_time, doc.ref);\\n }\\n}\\n\">>,\n                      nil,[]}],\n                 nil,0,0,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,\n           nil,#{}},\n             <<\"shards/80000000-ffffffff/sessionmanager.1715319230\">>,\n          <<57,223,102,9,37,185,190,225,163,76,226,3,131,31,109,177>>}},\n     infinity]}",
    "ref": 352762430 }

